# Android error in webview.loadUrl() - Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl

I have a `webview` for load url, but not work.

Look at my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    //Log.d("rudyy", "aqui");
    wv.loadUrl("https://tripulanteaims.tam.com.br/wtouch/wtouch.exe/index");
    //Log.d("rudyy", "fim");


  }
}
```

When execute this code, android return this error :

```
Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Help-me please.

Answer (score 53):

Create a WebViewClient:

```
private class WvClient extends WebViewClient 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
        handler.proceed(); 
        // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
}
```

And set the initialized WebViewClient ("WvClient") to your WebView ("wv" in that case):

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WvClient());
```

**Or in one line:**

```
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {@Override public void onReceivedSslError(WebView v, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er){ handler.proceed(); }});
```

Comment: will be the same with anon 


```webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
        handler.proceed();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is simply ignoring all SSL errors. Definitely not a good solution.

Comment: but *why* is it getting an SSL error when my browser says the same site I am using has a good cert???

Answer (score 12):

I was dealing with this and quite frankly allowing MITM attacks is a no-no. Here is a cleaner solution that supports pinning. Save the certificate into your raw resource folder.
NOTE: Sadly, SSLError gives us an SslCertificate when you call getCertificate(). SslCertificate is kind of useless. It's public API doesn't allow you to verify the public key, only the created on, expired date, issued to, issued by. However, if you open up this class you will see an X509Certificate member variable that is un-exposed. IDK why this design decision was taken. But there is an API for getting the Bundle, and that X509 Certificate member variable gets stored in there. So we access it that way, because the Certificate has a lot more useful methods on it.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    SslCertificate sslCertificateServer = error.getCertificate();
    Certificate pinnedCert = getCertificateForRawResource(R.raw.your_cert, mContext);
    Certificate serverCert = convertSSLCertificateToCertificate(sslCertificateServer);

    if(pinnedCert.equals(serverCert)) {
        handler.proceed();
    } else {
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}

public static Certificate getCertificateForRawResource(int resourceId, Context context) {
    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    Certificate ca = null;
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    InputStream caInput = resources.openRawResource(resourceId);

    try {
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            caInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
        }
    }

    return ca;
}

public static Certificate convertSSLCertificateToCertificate(SslCertificate sslCertificate) {
    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    Certificate certificate = null;
    Bundle bundle = sslCertificate.saveState(sslCertificate);
    byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("x509-certificate");

    if (bytes != null) {
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            certificate = cert;
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
        }
    }

    return certificate;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan... we just have to override these methods?

Comment: @RickON extend WebViewClient and yes, override the onReceivedSslError method.

Comment: FYI, If you use certificate pinning and the certificate that you are pinning to gets changed, your app will break. Just something to consider...

Comment: @MehulRanpara what is the basis of this statement?

Answer (score 4):

**This is the proper solution and google will approve your app by implementing below code:**

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    // for SSLErrorHandler
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
    builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

**If you use below code then at the time of debug it'll work but google will reject your app:**

```
private class WvClient extends WebViewClient 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
        handler.proceed(); 
        // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the most voted answers will not be accepted by google play if you publish the app.I got the following message when submitting the app: We reviewed APPNAME, with package name APP.PACKAGE, and found that your app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users. SSL Error Handler

Thank you for giving a valid/good solution.