# Empty response from asp.net application on emulator

Tags: android, asp.net, android-studio, android-emulator, localhost

I can't browse to my web application from visual studio while using a android emulator. I get an empty response error on the browser. When I browse to my local application from my computer, it works. I used the ip 10.0.2.2 on android emulator instead of localhost. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Can you clarify about how the emulator works using 10.0.2.2 (alias)?

Answer (score 0):

Check your console for any errors. I was having this issue and was seeing `Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.` because my locally issued certificate was invalid.

For development [I overrode WebviewClient according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33825905/3570019) and was able to get it working. Make sure to remove before releasing to production to prevent your application from being susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks.