# webview does not open long urls (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, webview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVso4.jpg)

I have to open a very long url with webview. The url is very similar to this one, but when it is inserted it does not load.

But when I try a shorter url everything works perfect. The problem is that if or if the length of the url has to be that (that is, the long url)

Will anyone know how to solve it? Thank you.
I buy code.

```
https://urlqueriurl.com/?token=gSzoBKIDAIzM4+mpHqGIe3FAT6qjRlJNnKgWmWGe+rfoJIDxBU+xTbgb2wATwMAOa5c/W97E9JIEb/++aN6UzNVfMr60uiFv8EIBqNzp5eteLDfdlQGZktVVtAH7RnDsowPsSJooPF4YGTrC9fdDdu7Y3nzLIRDjos85eQok5+q7n0y3OVdC9ry56u6IftAoPYD+TlDNbgK0CPF/79yS5Uah/srZ2n+xGjQkixngqObKfptpSHo2hWW0JpRv0Jr4X9G9O51OxSdFrmFNU53AqgUSNSO6epDXNa1CzDR1v5qsVBSnkM+j+yxEhbEBUBAPWuAKIzWbZ+IBzL7z6kH/xA==.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.0Z+Yvj20pc/uMd266lnEhINHlL6c2RAEtp28rneyu+IfRurEYIqf5I5NTkxYzWGxl2kUrywXU0VE+sueU+naBFEIPRqTwMqB2GTbfObrHdQzXYzwFKuVu5z68DD5t0y/4YemTvYjOrTomkvqGKD2a4LwDe+vOIfIQw6qiQeEVCQaiRg/jLAil3+6Y8D5JG5TgFvvrTVb9LZx8oF6rQR5WTHbsz0Q9P9/Ch8VBG5sRM/KJiaQpjOBldJSz2ThjaDVLv1kwkvmhfcux1thD5r2Omy/yN30KYEicNboHu9hsf8TX4QiVNCBd0dg+M1TtvtVz4DFpx5mk/aSTiTRQSu7Ug=="
```

```html
wv = findViewById(R.id.wv_webView);
String url =  getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
getSupportActionBar().hide();
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
wv.clearHistory();
wv.clearFormData();
wv.clearCache(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

IN LocCast:

```
2021-05-04 19:35:32.318 9524-9817/ar.com.bp.android E/IBM.MCE 3.7.1.2.14 : EventsManager: Error while trying to send all events
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:229)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:299)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:472)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.sendQuery(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.sendQuery(Unknown Source:53)
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.post(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.postJson(Unknown Source:5)
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsManager.sendEvents(Unknown Source:60)
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsManager.sendAllEvents(Unknown Source:57)
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsJob.startJob(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.job.MceJobService$1.run(Unknown Source:12)
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:208)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:404)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:299) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:472) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.sendQuery(Unknown Source:0) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.sendQuery(Unknown Source:53) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.post(Unknown Source:8) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.postJson(Unknown Source:5) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsManager.sendEvents(Unknown Source:60) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsManager.sendAllEvents(Unknown Source:57) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsJob.startJob(Unknown Source:7) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.job.MceJobService$1.run(Unknown Source:12) 
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339) 
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94) 
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:208) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:404) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:299) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:472) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.sendQuery(Unknown Source:0) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.sendQuery(Unknown Source:53) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.post(Unknown Source:8) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.util.HttpHelper.postJson(Unknown Source:5) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsManager.sendEvents(Unknown Source:60) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsManager.sendAllEvents(Unknown Source:57) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.events.EventsJob.startJob(Unknown Source:7) 
    at com.ibm.mce.sdk.job.MceJobService$1.run(Unknown Source:12)
```

Comment: Could you please check logcat and share the error?

Comment: edited, there I put the logcas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android error in webview.loadUrl() - Trust anchor for certification path not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825696/android-error-in-webview-loadurl-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-fou)